# How to get this template in Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to get this template style in my Angular app:

```
----------------------------------------------------
               FIXED HEADER
----------------------------------------------------
  S   |
  I   |
  D   |
  E   |
  N   |           MAIN SCROLLABLE AREA
  A   |
  V   |
      |
      |
      |
```

In this template the header is always visible on the top (fixed) and the main area is scrollable independently from the sidenav.

I know what Angular components I have to use, but I dont know what css styles apply to get the desired result.

I tried the following:

```
.fixedHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

With this CSS I obtain the desired result in the fixed header but the rest of the content gets overlaped by the header. If I apply a margin-top to sidenav and main area I can fix this overlapping but playing around with the margin-top px 
it does not seem to be the right way to do it.

The app code:

In app.component.html I use two custom components:

```
<mt-toolbar></mt-toolbar>
<mt-sidenav></mt-sidenav>
```

The mt-toolbar component:

The html

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z4" color="primary" class="fixedHeader">
    TITLE
</mat-toolbar>
```

The CSS

```
.fixedHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
 }
```

The mt-sidenav component:

The html

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened disableClose>
        <mat-nav-list>
          SIDENAV ITEMS
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
         ## MAIN SCROLLABLE AREA ##
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: You should add more code. Give us the app as it currently stands and we'll be able to see the problem much quicker.

Comment: But a top margin (or if you want, top padding) is the standard way of positioning main content below a fixed header. Now sure what better way you expect. Well, you can position the main content relatively of course.

Comment: It is possible to calculate that top margin automatically based on the height of the toolbar, without specifying it "by hand"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place the *mat-toolbar* above the *mat-sidenav-container* (or *mat-drawer-container*) and set the [mat-sidenav input *fixedInViewport* to true + set *fixedTopGap*](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api) to 64px when the width of the window is >= 600px otherwise 56px.

The class is not necessary then, it will always be above the scrollable content, so it doesn't need `position: fixed;`. For the *mat-elevation-z4* to work indeed you need to set it to `position: relative;` and `z-index: 1;`

To observe the width of the window I am using [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) and the *ObservableMedia* service of it. You could also overwrite the mat-toolbars height to always have a height of 64px for instance.

Here is [an example](https://github.com/Birdperson90/birdperson90-blog/blob/master/src/app/core/containers/layout.component.ts) where I have implemented it.

**Edit:**
Here is a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-fixed-sidenav) on stackblitz.

Comment: This solves the problems in the sidenav but not in the sidenav's content (the main area). This main area pushes upwards the toolbar on scroll due to the elimination of the "position: fixed" in the toolbar.

Comment: It should not do that, for me it works that way. The toolbar sticks above the scrollable content, with the sidenav clipped below it. Only the content in the middle is scrollable. Could you please provide some more code of yours?

Comment: I realize that in your example you don't use "<mat-sidenav-content>" to place the main content. Removing this solves the scroll problem, but why?

Comment: Idk, maybe it is related to styles in there but it is not necessary to use it, doesn't even have any inputs or outputs.